# C# outputting dynamic data in 2 columns bootstrap grid

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap

I have x amount of data I want to display in 2 columns. Assuming I am looping through the data, how can I display it in 2 columns using a bootstrap grid?
(Using Razor in an MVC partial view)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           item 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            item 2
        </div>
    </div>
...
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           item x - 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            item x
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what type of project (MVC, forms, etc?) you're using it's hard to say because you need some logic in the UI to iterate through your data set. For example,

**with C# MVC & Razor, you might do this:**

```
@foreach(record in x)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @record.someValue
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @record.someOtherValue
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I have the loop, but I get the same data for both columns in each row. Each "i" is a different "record" in your example.